# Any server like jboss or tomcat, I want to instantiate a class from a deployed application

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

Is there a way that I can instantiate a Class in a deployed application by another deployed application if I know the package name and class I wan to instantiate? In any jboss or tomcat?

Thanks & regards,
~K.

Comment: If you want it for unit testing, then you should consider using a mock object instead of the real class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that by [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

---

**Example**

```
Bar aBar;
String barClassName = getBarImplClass();
aBar =
  (Bar) Class.forName(barClassName).newInstance();
```